# update multiple rows based on conditions

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I would like to update three columns simutaneously based on one column

My data looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(input = c("Antidesma cuspidatum Mull.Arg.", "Antidesma cuspidatum Müll.Arg.", 
                  "Alchornea parviflora (Benth.) Mull.Arg.", "Alchornea parviflora (Benth.) Müll.Arg."),
                 n1 = c("Antidesma cuspidatum", NA, "Alchornea parviflora", NA),
                 n2 = c("Antidesma", NA, "Alchornea", NA),
                 n3 = c("Phyllanthaceae", NA, "Euphorbiaceae", NA))

                                    input                   n1        n2             n3
1          Antidesma cuspidatum Mull.Arg. Antidesma cuspidatum Antidesma Phyllanthaceae
2          Antidesma cuspidatum Müll.Arg.                 <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
3 Alchornea parviflora (Benth.) Mull.Arg. Alchornea parviflora Alchornea  Euphorbiaceae
4 Alchornea parviflora (Benth.) Müll.Arg.                 <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
```

I would like to ask if I find the first two `strings` of `input` column are the same , then the coresponding rows would be the same. It means that the value (2nd and 4th rows) of `n1`, `n2`, `n3` in this example would be added by the value (1st and 3rd rows).

My desired output here

```
                                    input                   n1        n2             n3
1          Antidesma cuspidatum Mull.Arg. Antidesma cuspidatum Antidesma Phyllanthaceae
2          Antidesma cuspidatum Müll.Arg. Antidesma cuspidatum Antidesma Phyllanthaceae
3 Alchornea parviflora (Benth.) Mull.Arg. Alchornea parviflora Alchornea  Euphorbiaceae
4 Alchornea parviflora (Benth.) Müll.Arg. Alchornea parviflora Alchornea  Euphorbiaceae
```

Any sugesstions for me this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dplyr` package.
First I create a column `gr` which contains only the first two strings of `input`. Then I change (or `mutate`) the columns `n1`, `n2` and `n3` by putting the non-NA value of that group there.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(gr = gsub("(^\\w+ \\w+) .*", "\\1", input)) %>%
  mutate(across(c(n1, n2, n3), ~.x[!is.na(.x)][1])) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for helping me this question. I would like to ask you question about this line `mutate(across(c(n1, n2, n3), ~.x[!is.na(.x)][1]))`. Could you explain me why this help for my case please?

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
# Resolve the names of column vectors prefixed with "n":
# na_col_names => character vector
na_col_names <- grep(
  "n\\d+",
  names(df),
  value = TRUE
)

# Carry the last value forward: df => data.frame
df[,na_col_names] <- lapply(
  na_col_names,
  function(x){
    df[,x] <- na.omit(df[,x])[cumsum(!(is.na(df[,x])))]  
  }
)
```

Tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate_if(
    str_detect("n\\d+", names(.)),
    function(x){
      fill(x, .direction = "down")
    }
  )
```